# Setting path to run files in 'Lua for windows'

Tags: windows, command-line, path, lua

My question is this: I am trying to learn how to program in Lua to make Addons for World of Warcraft. I bought 'Programming in Lua- by Roberto Ierusalimschy, 3rd edition' to teach myself the language. After downloading 'Lua for windows' to perform the examples in the book I cannot figure out how to call files from the command window (I can write a program in SciTE and run it and it will run in the bottom window of that program, but that's not what I am trying to do)

For example if I have a .lua file saved in a folder somewhere called `hello.lua` the book is telling me I can just type `% lua hello.lua`to run the file, but I am getting the following error.

> stdin:1: unexpected symbol near'%'

I am guessing this is because I have not told it what folder to look for this file in, but I cannot figure out how to tell it which file to look in. Any suggestions?

Is there a default folder somewhere that it has not told me about that I am supposed to save all of my programs to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the book

```
% lua hello.lua
```

The `%` is supposed to be the prompt in Unix-like systems. In Windows, if you are already in the current path of the file in the command line, you can simply type:

```
lua hello.lua
```

[image]

Note that the 3rd edition of the PiL book is about Lua 5.2, but the current Lua-for-windows is version 5.1.4 (You can run `lua -v` to confirm.

Comment: @RBerteig Good point, but the book is still about Lua 5.2, so some attention should be paid.

Comment: And that *is* likely to become a stumbling block of some form when the exercises trip over some of the differences in the language. Of course, since WoW is still 5.1, the OP is going to have stumbles there too.

Comment: Ok, so the % is not for windows. Are you using command prompt in the screenshot? Or are you using the Lua command executor? How do you change the path of the file in the command line? You have 'cd temp' to change the path to some kind of temporary file I am assuming, what does the cd stand for, change directory? Say I wanted to change the path to a folder in libraries>documents>lua files how would I tell it to look there?

Comment: @user2977554 I'm using the Windows command line(`cmd`). I'm using `cd` to change directory to the folder where `hello.lua` is. Your question is more about `cmd` than Lua, try type the disk where the file is like `D:`, then `cd libraries\documents`, `cd "lua files"` etc.